# Imagem não troca quando clica nela, somente no texto

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com um problema, tenho um projeto com vários collapses e para indicar abertura e fechamento dos collapses, eu coloquei uma seta para a direita e ao clicar no texto, ela vira para baixo e o collapse abre, porém, caso clicar na própria seta, o collapse abre porém a imagem não muda. Eu gostaria que ela mudasse junto, como eu poderia fazer?

Código HTML do collapse

```
        <h1 index="1" class="collapsed change" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
        href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" ng-click="alert_step2()">

        <img index="1" class="change img-change" src="assets/img/arrow_right.png"
        style="width: 20px; height: 25px">Step 2 - Acknowledge Your Strengths (highest scores)</h1>

                        </h1>
```

Código JS para troca de imagem

```
    $('.change').click(function (){
    var img1 = 'assets/img/arrow_right.png';
    var img2 = 'assets/img/arrow_down.png';
    var index = $(this).attr('index');
    var element = $('img[index='+index+']');
    if(element.attr('src') === img1){
    element.attr('src',img2);
    }else if(element.attr('src') === img2){
    element.attr('src',img1);

     }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acontece pelo seletor '.change' o evento está sendo disparado duas vezes, quando você clica na imagem ele troca para a seta para baixo e na sequência retorna para a da direita... Mude o seu seletor para `'h1.change'`.

```js
$('h1.change').on('click', function() {
  var img1 = 'https://www.thetactilegroup.com/images/arrow_right.png';
  var img2 = 'https://www.thetactilegroup.com/images/arrow_down.svg';
  var index = $(this).attr('index');
  var element = $('img[index=' + index + ']');
  if (element.attr('src') === img1) {
    element.attr('src', img2);
  } else if (element.attr('src') === img2) {
    element.attr('src', img1);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 index="1" class="collapsed change" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" ng-click="alert_step2()">
  <img index="1" class="change img-change" src="https://www.thetactilegroup.com/images/arrow_right.png" style="width: 30px; height: 30px">Step 2 - Acknowledge Your Strengths (highest scores)
</h1>
```

Comment: Não acredito que a resposta era tão simples... Obrigado muito pela ajuda! Ainda preciso estudar mais JS!